# which IDE is used for developing application in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I am new in Phonegap.i am currently working in iOS Application developer.
I want to Start develop application using Phonegap.I want to know which development platform (IDE) is used to develop Phonegap application?

Can i develop whole application using Dreamweaver?

I don't wish to used Phonegap in Xcode.
is there any way to used in window PC for develop iOS application using Phonegap?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581330/what-ide-for-phonegap-is-eclipse-enough

Comment: @Keith can i develop application using Dreamweaver?

Comment: Yes. All you need is an HTML+Javascript editor.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to develop application for Phonegap or Apache Cordova, you have many IDE's at your disposal:

1. [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/) now supports the development of Cordova apps.. Check out the [tools for Apache Cordova](https://www.visualstudio.com/explore/cordova-vs).
2. The [Eclipse THyM](https://www.eclipse.org/thym/) project adds support for developing Hybrid Mobile apps with Cordova / Phonegap
3. [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) provide native support [for developing Cordova / Phonegap Apps](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/cordova-gettingstarted.html)
4. [Jetbrains WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) provides [support for Cordova](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-phonegap-cordova.html)
5. Intel released the [Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk) and it provides and easy, visual way to build Cordova / Phonegap apps

Comment: I love WebStorm, it's so good to hear I can write apps with the IDE of my love.

Comment: More info from JetBrains here. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-phonegap-cordova.html Also for VS2019 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62136506/how-to-open-a-2017-cordova-project-in-visual-studio-2019

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

Visual Studio 2017 is the last version of VS with first-party support for Cordova and PhoneGap. [Visual Studio 2019 no-longer supports it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/515222/re-enable-tools-for-apache-cordova-on-visual-studi.html). [The official guidance is to use Visual Studio Code or stick with VS2017 instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019).

#### Old, obsolete answer:

Visual Studio 2013 supports developing for Cordova (PhoneGap) [with a new first-party add-in](https://web.archive.org/web/20140614154641/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381.aspx) - it's stll in the preview stage, but try it out :)

Disclaimer: I work on this! :D

Comment: It's a 404. Page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago I'd say IntelXDK is the best way to develop cross platform apps, especially has it had a really nice build process so you could develop, build and publish direct to the relevant app store.

Sadly IntelXDK is no more....

So I moved over to Visual Studio.  Although more complicated to set up, and you needed a Mac for iOS development as well, it was the next best option (IMHO).

Sadly Visual Studio 2019 has dropped cordova as well.  I guess in order to push people towards Xamarin.  Personally I think Xamarin (hybrid apps) need a lot more work by Microsoft.  Having to write everything in XAML is a pain, blender support would have been nice.

So you can either go back to Visual Studio 2017 or try your luck at Visual Studio Code (But that's just an editor and not an IDE)

At the moment of typing this I'm still searching for an alternative, but have gone back to VS2017.

@Dai would be interested to hear you thoughts on VS2019 dropping Cordova.