# How to open a 2017 Cordova project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, phonegap, visual-studio-cordova

I have a Visual Studio project written using Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Apache Cordova, and I am unable to open it in Visual Studio 2019 (Message: incompatible) and there is no available Cordova project types. What's the best way to be able to open/edit/redeploy a Tools for Apache Cordova project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't open it from visual 2019, because Microsoft stop supporting Cordova.

The best way is to install visual 2017 for Apache Cordova projects only (to be lite in usage) and install latest version of Cordova globally.