# Different between phonegap and intel xdk or others

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

So, i just beginning to make hybrid mobile apps, and at first i'm going to learn phonegap but after reading some article there is mentioned about intel XDK which do what that phonegap can do but in more straight forward instalation(it have ide, emulator and so on)

so what is the difference between those? and which one is better in term of getting tutorials, community support and supported api for mobile platform?

or is it the same thing? since intel xdk can be integrated with phonegap, so it's very confusing...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Generally speaking you have different types of frameworks aimed to build hybrid apps :

- Frameworks targetting HTML5 content like Cordova or intel XDK (both via JS byte code), Intel XDK is based on Cordova
- Frameworks like [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/) which render the UI using the platform’s native controls but still working via JS
- Free (or partially free) Frameworks aiming to produce real native code like [Unity](http://unity3d.com/libgdx) (C# orJS based, Games oriented), [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) (Python Based) or [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) (Java based, Game Oriented)
- Commercial Frameworks aiming to produce real native code like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) (using C#) or [Embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio)
  New Frameworks are coming and my list is probably incomplete.

As you see, the choice is very broad now !

Cordova and XDK are not too difficult to begin with but will show their limits shortly because they produce HTML5, not native code.

Titanium is a good choice if you want to code only in HTML/JS and have access to mobile platforms native controls. It has now an MVC Framework called Alloy. It produce rather big applications even for HelloWorld as will do most of these tools !

Unity is the best if you want to build something like a multi-platform Game.
It cross-platform habilities are amazing

Xamarin is good and not very expensive if you like C#.

Choose Kivy if you want to develop with Python/Pygames tools and libgdx if you are a Java addict.

Comment: Wow, thank you for detailed explanation and i already check each framework that you mentioned.

Comment: Qt (C++) is another option for free/commercial license that produce real native code.

Comment: "It produce rather big applications even for HelloWorld as will do most of these tools !"

Wrong! https://itunes.apple.com/app/news-mute/id879924920 (few MB's)

For sources: https://github.com/Adimpression/NewsMuteWWW

Answer (score 9):

To answer only the first part of the question: difference between PhoneGap and Intel XDK.

PhoneGap is a framework, that allows building multi-platform mobile apps from HTML and Javascript source, created and supported by Adobe. It is proprietary.

Cordova is open source version of PhoneGap maintained by Apache. 
Intel XDK is IDE based on Cordova.

The difference in creating apps with Cordova(or Phonegap) and Intel XDK is that in the first case you type commands in prompt window and in the second you click on IDE buttons.

The result application is supposed to be the same.

Comment: Actually, PhoneGap is a distribution of Cordova