# Support of PhoneGap in Aptana

Tags: cordova, titanium, emulation, aptana, aptana3

Is there any development bundle to extend the functionality of Aptana in order to support the latest version of PhoneGap?

I got PhoneGap from [here](http://phonegap.com/install/)

**Update**

I want to run PhoneGap through Aptana IDE as recommended here.

It recommends the Ripple emulator. Is it good?

How can I set PhoneGap to use it from Aptana? In the instructions of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gGBhaVG9CI) it seems very simple using some file but can I find from anywhere the latest version?

Phonegap converts the html. So it is not exactly a native app.

How about the solution of Titanium framework. Is this for native development or again uses html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a several subquestions wrapped up in your main question. So I will try to answer them one after the other.

**Is Ripple Emulator good?**

Well, good is a really broad term and it is not easy to define whether one thing is good for everyone or especially for you. [Ripple's](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc) main features though are kind of promising. I will just summarize them for you because I guess that you already read about them.

> The Ripple emulator is a multi-platform mobile environment emulator that is custom-tailored to mobile HTML5 application development and testing. The Ripple emulator is an extension to the Google Chrome browser that allows you to quickly see how your application looks and functions on multiple mobile devices and platforms.

And it's features:

> You can use the Ripple emulator to perform JavaScript debugging, HTML
>   DOM inspection, automated testing, and multiple device and screen
>   resolution emulation in real-time without redeploying the application
>   or restarting the emulator.

For more information please see the [documentation of Ripple on the Blackberry page](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v1_0/getting_started_with_ripple_1866966_11.html).

Although I think that Ripple is good enough to give it a try here are some links to possible alternatives:

1. [Opera Mobile Classic Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/mobile-emulator)
2. Another possibility is the inbuilt [device mode mobile emulator](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) feature in Google Chrome. (Hint: At the moment some features are only usable when you have the Chrome Canary Builds)

I do not have any experience with any of them. I would recommend Ripple and if there is something which does not satisfy your needs try the other emulators. If you have problems setting Ripple up please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17695875/2439890) which has very detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697235/2439890) showing the setup process step by step.

**How do I set up Aptana and Phonegap?**

First of all, is there any special reason why you want to use Aptana? As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17585531/2439890) states Eclipse has everything you need to develop a proper PhoneGap application. Additionally you could also integrate Aptana as a plugin into Eclipse. Please notice that the IDE you use must also match the platforms you target. Have a look at a part of the recommend answer:

> For ease of development I'd recommend installing one of the IDEs
>   (probably whatever matches the physical devices you have for testing
>   or prefer). This way you get IDE assistance like Intellisense, but as
>   I said it's not strictly required to have one.
>
> Your alternative if you want to compile for all those platforms
>   locally is pretty ridiculous:
>
> iOS - install Xcode
>
> Android/BlackBerry - install Eclipse
>
> Windows Phone - install Visual Studio

Since you did not specify your target platform I would recommend to use one of these first and if you are not happy with them choose another one if possible.

**What about Titanium?**

Titanium is no native alternative. Titanium applications are built using JavaScript and xml. Although you could even use it with JavaScript only (not recommended anymore). It allows to build simple apps really fast and for both, Android and iOS (and some more operating systems like Blackberry) but it is not made for (a) apps needing excessive amounts of memory because the performance is sometimes really bad even for basic stuff and (b) apps that need a complicated layout since it is not easy to maintain the layout across several devices. I build an app with the framework last autumn and I had a great start but in the end it was really difficult to get things working perfectly.

If you have JavaScript skills and a very simple app it could be an alternative for you. Otherwise I would not recommend it.