# Is there a phonegap iphone emulator

Tags: iphone, emulation, phonegap-build

Is there a way to test PhoneGap projects on various iPhones using an emulator. I am using the PhoneGap Build website.

I can do this easily with Appcelerator projects but can't see how to do this with PhoneGap.

Comment: Did you get your question answered?

Comment: No no replies so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bill,
There are several classes of emulators that you can use for Phonegap, and all mobile development.

1. webbrowsers in emulation (responsive) mode
2. Wienre (comes with server)
3. Ripple (work with Google Chrome)
4. IDE (eclipse, Android Studio, etc.

On #1, Google Chrome is the most popular and there are several plugins, Ripple being the most popular. Firefox has plugins and most people use Firebug. The browsers are mainly use for UI development. They all to a varying degree have WEB API access(1), which is good for testing but requires side steps to integrate with phonegap (so most people only do rudimentary testing with Web API). Firefox *ctrl+shft+m* ; Google Chrome *ctrl+shft+i* (then look for phone icon)

On #2, [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) (pronounced winery), launches a window in emulator mode and has access to the console. This allows additional messages, more than in webbrowswer emulation mode.

On #3, [Ripple](http://emulate.phonegap.com/) is a favorite because it works with Google Chrome. It is similar to Wienre, but has no server.

On #4, Many of the mentioned IDEs have an emulator built in, or use an SDK to accomplish the same task.

**Added Sept 1, 10:30pm PDT**
There is this also.
*What IDE for Phonegap? Is Eclipse enough? [closed]*
[Which IDE for Phonegap? Is Eclipse enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581330/what-ide-for-phonegap-is-eclipse-enough)

Best of Luck
Jesse

**Footnotes**

#1 - Many of the plugins have an API base on Web API.

Comment: Brilliant answer many thanks for that. I did try Ripple but it doesn't do iPhone 6. The Chrome developer tools look pretty good.